# How to point to the exact select's option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

Below is my option

```
<select name="currency" id="currency">
  <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
  <option value="BDT">BDT</option>
  <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
  <option value="JPY">JPY</option>
  <option value="USD">USD</option>
  <option value="USDT">USDT</option>
</select>
```

How do I set USD as the default value? (This default value can be **dynamically changed**, so it cannot hard code set USD as the default value)

The solution that I had tested :  `$('select[name="currency"] option:contains("USD")').prop('selected', true);` but it will show USDT instead of USD

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by dinamically changed you mean using js:

```js
const dynamicDefaultJsVal = 'USD';

$('#currency').val(dynamicDefaultJsVal); // jQuery

// document.querySelector('#currency').value = dynamicDefaultJsVal; // Vanilla js
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="currency" id="currency">
  <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
  <option value="BDT">BDT</option>
  <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
  <option value="JPY">JPY</option>
  <option value="USD">USD</option>
  <option value="USDT">USDT</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
<select name="currency" id="currency">
  <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
  <option value="BDT">BDT</option>
  <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
  <option value="JPY">JPY</option>
  <option value="USD" selected>USD</option>
  <option value="USDT">USDT</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Directly from the question: "*This default value can be dynamically changed, so it cannot [be] hard code[d]"*

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#currency').val("USD");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or an update to your question? In the first case, please read [answer] and then [edit] the answer to clarify. In the second case, please delete this and edit your question instead.